# Jokes in Miles Reid's 'Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry'

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

In the index of this book, under j, he references several 'jokes' found throughout the text.  I can't find one on page 91 - anyone know what it is?

Comment: Well, may be that's the joke.

Comment: Maybe "Central Electricity" in the top figure?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that this is an appropriate question for MO.

Comment: Much as I'm fond of UAG, I'm inclined to regard this question as "too localized".

Comment: It might have something to do with the "Central electricity" on the ruled surface.  I have not been that long in the UK to actually understand the joke, though.

It's questionable whether this is an appropriate question, though.  I'm voting to close.


Comment: On page 87 he has (GOTO (5.9) if you want to avoid a headache) which is similar to the indexed jokes.

Comment: I can't recommend enough reading the "history and sociology of the modern subject", starting on page 114. It is a funny but also incredibly opinionated and informed piece: I have rarely read anything as blunt written about  a group of mathematicians (namely Parisian algebraic geometers).

Comment: @Georges: Is that the book where he quotes someone saying sarcastically "but the twisted cubic is an excellent example of a pro-representable functor"? Or is that in his Undergraduate Commutative Algebra?

Comment: Yes, Yemon, it is the book called "Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry", not the Commutative Algebra one. I hope the quotation you give will entice our colleagues into reading Miles Reid's polemical sociological observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Robert, the joke on page 91 is that the ruled quadric depicted has "Central Electricity" written over it. It is an allusion to the cooling towers used by power plants. Here is the obligatory Wikipedia link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooling_tower

Comment: At the bottom of page 90 he mentions civil engineering and the advantages of this shape for building a curved surface out of concrete. 

Comment: By the way Miles Reid is one ot the three only Ph.D. students Pierre Deligne ever had ( Rapoport and Le Dung Trang are the other two).Subject of thesis? Quadrics!